# How to get Google Profile Information of a User in Django?

Tags: django, profile

Is it possible to get a User's Information from Google Profile using Django?

For example, i have an application which does user profiling and the user wants to update the information by his/her google profile.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should look here http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/apis/gdata/articles/python_client_lib.html since gdata provides access to all data stored in Google